# Base64 image only shows in desktop web view

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I developed QR Code generator when I click the button.

And QR code is created with Base64/png images.

When I click button it gets current URL's QR code. And actually it works find in desktop chrome.

But there is problem in mobile view. I tested with mobile browsers with Google Chrome and Samsung Browser and both browser's doesn't shows the QR code image. (I tested Real Nexus 5, Real Nexus 7, Real Galaxy Note 8)

So I tested with desktop Google Chrome developer tools with Nexus 5 and other devices it works.

And I found that even if I use mobile chrome or Samsung browser when I checked desktop mode, it works fine..

So I really don't know where the problem from.

You can access with this [link](https://expressme.herokuapp.com/sangumee) and click the QR code button.

Comment: you should share here some code. The code relevant to this question. Not links but code (as text)

Comment: I opened your link in Samsung's Google Chrome ,iOS Google Chrome, iOS Safari Browser it works perfectly. If you need screenshot for that please let me know. Thanks.